# webassembly is not defined on ms-edge in github editor [FIXED]

Tags: github, microsoft-edge, webassembly

GitHub code editor (github.dev) on Microsoft Edge browser says the error `request initialize failed with message: Webassembly is not defined` and also missing syntax highlighting while opening a file (e.g. a simple .cs file)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do to fix that is to go to the `edge settings` > `privacy, search, and services` > scroll down to reach option `Enhance your security on the web`, and just `turn it off` (note that you must completely turn it off, not setting it on Balanced or strict.)

[image]

or you can create exception:
[image]

after that refresh the github and see it working...

hope this saves you time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes actually I am waiting to pass 2 days to mark it as accepted. appreciated you reminding.

Answer (score 4):

As of now (2022.5), the above exceptions list no longer works. Disabling Enhanced Security feature is never an option for me.

Users should add the following sites to exceptions. Mind the `[*.]` wildcard, it's mandatory.

```
github.dev
[*.]vscode-webview.net
```

If you are using vscode.dev, you should add it either

```
vscode.dev
```

If you are using VSCode Web insider builds (click `Switch to Insider Versions...` on bottom-left ), add the following domain.

```
[*.]vscode-cdn.net
```

adding `github.com` is not necessary, the actual workers are not running from this domain.

---

Update:

Currently (07/2022) the following works for me:

```
github.dev
[*.]vscode-cdn.net
```